# For a continuous function $f$, find the value of $\int_{0}^{\infty}[ f(x^n+x^{-n}) \frac{\log x}{x} +\frac{1}{1+x^2}]dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

The expression simplifies down to
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[%
\operatorname{f}\left(\,{x^{n} +
x^{-n}}\,\right)\,\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{x} \right]\mathrm{d}x +\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
I have a feeling that th first integral would end up being zero, but I don’t really know the mechanism for it.

Can I get a hint $?$.

Comment: Sub $x$ with $1/x$

Comment: @Integrand can u add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work: the first part is $0$ *only if it's convergent*, and continuity of $f$ isn't nearly sufficient for that, it doesn't even work for $f\equiv1$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector According to the answer, it has to be zero

Comment: The integral $\int^\infty_0\frac{\log x}x$ is divergent. Period.

Comment: @ProfessorVector fair enough, although substituting $1/x$ does seem to get $I=0$.

Comment: If you believe in $\infty-\infty=0$, it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115475/discussion-between-aditya-and-professor-vector).

Comment: @ProfessorVector at the level I am working at, it might be a fair assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result must independent from $f$ and from $n$, otherwise the question made no sense.  Take $f(x)=x/2$ and $n=0$ so the integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{x}\,dx$$
which diverges.